# reCAPTCHA box not being aligned correctly

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

I can't get to align correctly the reCAPTCHA form on my registration page. Even if the `div` it is contained in has `text-align` set to `center`, it is displayed on the left of the page:
[image: Bugged version: the reCAPTCHA is on the left]
While if I change its `align` via JavaScript (`document.getElementById("recaptcha_widget_div").align = "right"`) it works correctly (screenshot taken in the middle of the page):
[image: Correct version: the reCAPTCHA is in the middle]

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hw7rX/)'s a fiddle with the div and the entire CSS called in the page.

Comment: Please post your HTML/CSS.

Comment: I posted the fiddle, as requested.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm posting an updated solution to this question, as the accepted solution does not work with the new version 2.0 of Google's ReCaptcha.

Correct formatting is:

```
.g-recaptcha div { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
```

The new ReCaptcha uses a single `div` class called `g-recaptcha` and a number of unidentified and unclassified `div` children. This is probably the cleanest safest way to get the widget to center properly.

Answer (score 13):

You need this css rule:

```
#recaptcha_area { margin: auto}
```

Comment: I vote this as the best solution, as it's the most clean and doesn't result in moving the form (the other solutions move the form to the left).

Answer (score 3):

I would target the actual form. Since width is already set, you can have it align correctly by adding margin.

```
#recaptcha_area {
         margin: auto;
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hw7rX/5/)

Comment: I voted Fred's answer because it was the quickest *correct* one. Also, it looks like you don't need to apply the rule to #recaptcha_table.

Answer (score 3):

@fred02138's solution did not work for me and I had to add **`display:table`** to the css:

```
#recaptcha_area {
    display:table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: No idea why, but this is also the only solution that has worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Set appropraite CSS on the form. It's all block elements so text-align:center won't work on it. text-align only works on inline elements.

However this will:

```
form { display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hw7rX/2/

Comment: It works, however it has the inconvenience of moving the form to the left.

Answer (score 0):

My approach will be to add a panel or div and put the reCaptcha inside of it. So you just have to align the panel or the div control instead of reCaptcha.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

i edit two selector

```
table {
text-align: center;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: auto;
width: 85%;
}

.label {
color: gray;
text-align: left;
width:160px;
}
```

here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hw7rX/1/)

Comment: This solution works too, but it moves the form to the left, so it's not okay.